# Android Pending intent with current application state

Tags: android

Say for example i have two activity . Activity A and Activity B. Activity A is my default launcher activity . And sometimes from background i launch activity B .

Now i put separate notification with pending intent which brings the user back to activity A by clicking on those.

But when my activity B is running ,when i press on my application icon ,android takes me to activity B.But when i click on notification,it takes me to Activity A as the pending intent points to Activity A.

how can i set pending intent  which will bring activity B on foreground if its running instead of activity A  ?

Thanks

NB : setting flag to re order activity wont work because when activity B is running, A is in back stack,so this flag will bring A to front.what i want is when user will click the notification,it will behave just as like the clicking application icon,that is bring activity B in foreground.

Comment: You can redirect to an application (or you can declare a new) class, which will launch activity B if its running, else launch activity A.

Comment: But that will not be a good solution. what i want is,i want to launch the current state of app with pending intent . like when i click on app icon,i want to do the same thing .so i was wondering if there is any special flag or way for that.